# How to create a custom formula within a Pivot table that selects values based on a list?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Hello all and thank you beforehand,

Let's say I have a pivot table that contains sales data per country:

| Country | Sales |
| --- | --- |
| Spain | 10 |
| France | 12 |
| UK. | 13 |

and I am trying to automate a report where based on a list of countries, the pivot only shows the countries included in the list.

| List of countries |
| --- |
| Spain |
| France |

Is there any custom formula you may think of for filtering in a pivot table values from a column contained within a range of cells?
Lets say List of countries is within: A21:A28 and column name of pivot is 'Country'.

Desired output in pivot:

| Country | Sales |
| --- | --- |
| Spain | 10 |
| France | 12 |

thank you

Comment: Kindly add input table and expected output table as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Comment: just edited and updated, thank you

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY(A1:B; "where A matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|"; 1; D2:D)&"'"; 1)
```

[image]

Comment: you saw [this](https://youtu.be/x1RVNGDSdw4)?  @player0

Comment: @Osm haha, nice find! we would either beat them badly in GS or not even qualify xD

Comment: I think is the latter, they use `MOD` alot :D    - @Player0